# How to clearInterval onClick while setInterval runs in componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs

I have a header whose background image can either change after a click or because of a setInterval loop.

The setInterval changes the image every 7 seconds, and is defined in componentDidMount.

When I click on a button to change the image, setInterval obviously doesn't care and keep running, so sometimes the user can't enjoy the new image more than a second.

How to reset setInterval when I click on a button? I can't write clearInterval() in my function handleClick(), because setInterval can't be accessed.

Comment: If that’s the case then increase the timer for setInterval

Comment: Why can you not use `clearInterval`? Can you explain further?

Comment: setInterval runs in componentDidMount. So I can't access it elsewhere. When I click on a button, it triggers a function handleClick(), that sends an action to a redux dispatcher, and if I write clearInterval(mysetintervalname) inside of this handleClick function, it doesn't do anything. It's a scope issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just save the interval into a class variable with `this.interval` so you can reach from anywhere.

```js
class Header extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.interval = setInterval(nextImage, 7000);
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    nextImage();
    this.interval = setInterval(nextImage, 7000);    
  }

  nextImage = () => {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```